# Java Thread/Runnable stop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a Client/Server application that is multithreaded to handle multiple connections. I have a parent class accepting the incoming connections, and an inner class to take the accepted Sockets and receiving the data and such.

I've noticed that though each thread is "finishing" and the `thread.join()` is being called, the memory allocated to the process is growing with each connection and never shrinking.

I don't think I'm able to share a lot of the code at the moment, but I have something like this to try to end the threads. I'm also positive that the run method is finishing. `ThreadHandler` is an inner-class containing the Thread and its Runnable. `IsRunning()` will return true after `run()` finishes.

```
private static void cleanupThreads(ArrayList<ThreadHandler> threads){

    //find all of the non-running threads and join them

    for(int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++){

        //get the Handler and check whether it's running
        ThreadHandler tmpThread = threads.get(i);
        Handler tmpHandler = tmpThread.getHandler();
        if(!tmpHandler.isRunning()){
            //time to die
            threads.remove(i);
            try{
                tmpThread.getThread().join();
                System.out.println("thread joined");
            }catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better option than pre-declaring ~10 threads and assigning them to Connections as they come? As is, calling `System.gc()` reduces the memory-load, but that's generally poor practice.

Comment: Can you show the code used to accept connections and create threads? That may be more relevant. Also, why do you think this is a memory problem? The behavior you describe is more or less normal and does not necessarily indicate a memory problem unless you are getting an OOME.

Comment: I would not say that a growing memory footprint is a problem, unless of course it is (eg OutOfMemoryError's). So, is it a problem? Are you receiving errors? Manually calling System.gc and seeing the memory reduce indicates there is not a 'leak'

Comment: The code used to accept connections is essentially the following. I can't post the run() method.

`Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();`
`Handler handler = new Handler(clientSocket);`
`Thread thread = new Thread(handler);`
`thread.start();`

I'm not getting an OOME, but I'm running tasklist and noticing that the Java process has gotten up to ~200MB after a few minutes' worth of unit-testing.

Comment: Are you positive that your code goes in the `if(!tmpHandler.isRunning())` block ? If for some reason the `isRunning()` method always returned `true` (eg. it reads a non-volatile `boolean`...), the block would never be executed and your `ArrayList<ThreadHandler>` would never shrink, effectively retaining the handlers and all their object graph in memory.

Comment: The print statement for joining is executing.

Comment: Are you using any `ThreadLocal` instances?  If you call `threadLocal.set(x)` from some thread A, and then thread A later exits, the ThreadLocal object will continue to hold the reference, and the object will never be garbage collected.

Comment: One much better option is to use the standard JDK thread pool called ExecutorService rather than writing your own. It's guaranteed to be written well and it's far easier for another developer to read and support: `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better option than pre-declaring ~10 threads and assigning them to Connections as they come?

No, that's generally a *good* idea because creating and destroying threads is much more expensive than re-using them.  The idea is called *Thread Pool*, and the Java standard library already implements one for you;  Look at the javadoc for java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor and related classes and interfaces.